# Maintaining a single instance over multiple JVM

Tags: java, synchronization, jvm, cluster-computing, distributed

I am creating a distributed service and i am looking at restricting a set of time consuming operations to a single thread of execution across all JVMs at any given time. (I will have to deal with 3 JVMs max).

My initial investigations point me towards java.util.concurrent.Executors , java.util.concurrent.Semaphore. Using singleton pattern and Executors or Semaphore does not guarantee me a single thread of execution across Multiple JVMs.

I am looking for a java core API (or at least a Pattern) that i can use to accomplish my task.

P.S: I have access to ActiveMQ within my existing project which i was planning to use in order to achieve single thread of execution across multiple JVM Machines only if i dont have another choice.

Comment: This is fairly difficult to achieve as JVMs don't know about each other. No internal `synchronization` will help you. I would recommend a `ServerSocket`, this way once one JVM has that socket open no other JVM can open it.

Comment: I think JMS is your best option. You could roll your own queue (store work records in a db table and then have a separate app that processes that queue) if you _really_ don't want to use JMS

Comment: Is an application server involved or is this a standalone app?

Comment: @bmorris591, i will give that a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: @Blake, ActiveMQ is a JMS implementation which i was planning to go with if i did not have a java Core API to help me. I chose ActiveMQ because of my familiarity with it.

Comment: @SzymonBiliński, Yup...i have Tomcat at my disposal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple solution for this with a core java API.  If the 3 JVMs have access to a shared file system you could use it to track state across JVMs.

So basically you do something like create a lock file when you start the expensive operation and delete it at the conclusion.  And then have each JVM check for the existence of this lock file before starting the operation.  However there are some issues with this approach like what if the JVM dies in the middle of the expensive operation and the file isn't deleted.

[ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org) is a nice solution for problems like this and any other cross process synchronization issue.  Check it out if that is a possibility for you.  I think it's a much more natural way to solve a problem like than a JMS queue.

Comment: The JVMs are always on separate file systems. This is for providing High availability capability.
If the JVMs could access a common shared file system, then the dead JVM situation you mention can be handled by having a max timeout configured and by looking at the last modified time of the lock file.
ZooKeeper looks promising.